# Media query for retina sprites

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to create two sets of sprites, one for normal dpi screens and one for retina dpi screens.

I've actually used gulp.spritesmith to generate the code and cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Both images exist, I can see the generated css looks right, it loads the different image and changes the background size, as it should, but when I view the page on a macbook pro retina, it still loads the regular sprite, not the retina one (the media query does not work).

```css
.compatibility-icon {
  background-image: url(/img/sprites/sprite.png);
  background-position: -117px 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .compatibility-icon {
    background-image: url(/img/sprites/sprite-2x.png);
    background-size: 197px 160px;
  }
}
```

Comment: is the mediaquery recognized by the browser?

Comment: how do I check that? it seems to render load the class in the @media at all (although they are there in the loaded css file), I'm testing with the latest version of chrome, safari for mac and firefox.

Comment: have you tried: @media  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
        only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    /* Style Rules */
}

Comment: The suggestion by @silviagreen ought to work, otherwise [this website](http://mediaqueriestest.com) may be useful to quickly test your media queries on any device. Also, note that the `device-pixel-ratio` value of 2 corresponds with `144dpi` for resolution (2x72dpi, the default screen resolution)

Comment: Alright, this works: @media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { /* Style Rules */ }

Now, any idea how to get spritesmith to do this :) ?

Comment: Ok, so both versions actually work. As I understand the one in my post is the latest recommended to be used.

I did not properly understand Gulp and the retina implementation of spritesmith.

Answer (score 2):

This actually works, the problem was a gulp configuration issue.

```css
.compatibility-icon {
  background-image: url(/img/sprites/sprite.png);
  background-position: -117px 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .compatibility-icon {
    background-image: url(/img/sprites/sprite-2x.png);
    background-size: 197px 160px;
  }
}
```